# how can i convert my system into a remote desktop server

Tags: 12.04, server, remote-desktop

We are a small team having limited resoueces but large projects and ideas. I use Ubuntu 12.04 on my system. I want to make my system usable to others also. Hence I want to convert it into a remote desktop server so that even while i am working on ubuntu they can use my system ( without effecting my work) just by logging in. Is it possible?

**Note**  I want to allow multiple user sessions at once

Thank you

Comment: Yes, this is possible in various ways. Linux is a multi-user system by design. What OS are your colleagues on?

Comment: @zwets Few have windows and others have ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

For the Ubuntu colleagues, create user accounts on your machine. Then have them login with `ssh -Y` and run their desired application. The `-Y` option allows the visual output to get tunneled to their box.

If you want your colleagues to have a full desktop environment, you could enable XDMCP on your box, and have them run one of the client solutions described in [the Ubuntu XDMCP documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/xdmcp). Note that running Unity or Gnome this way is pretty much out of the question, you could however give them a lightweight desktop environment such as XFCE.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program in Ubuntu named `Desktop sharing`. You can access it from dash (press `super key`).

Edit: For a `single user on remote Ubuntu/Linux` only one user can be logged on. If you want to share your screen try tools like `TeamViewer` and a greate `chrome extenssion` from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp.

Comment: but it will allow only one user at a time. How can i allow multiple users at one time

Comment: edited my answer ;)

Comment: I dont want to share my screen.:). I want to share my system and its resources.

Comment: For screen sharing you can use `teamviewer` and a good google chrome extenssion developed by google.

Comment: thank you both of u for these awesome solutions. But my requirement is actually different from them. I want to allow multiple user sessions on my system at once!! :)

Comment: I think you should assign a different username for each user and use simple desktop sharing. Also using project managment tools like  `git` and `svc` are good for teams.